# Changing the DNS servers Ubuntu Server 20.04 - Arm64 (Raspi)

Tags: dns, 20.04, raspberrypi, systemd-networkd

I am running Ubuntu server 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4 and I am having difficulty updating the DNS entry in `resolv.conf`. `resolv.conf` points to the nameserver `127.0.0.53`; however, I disabled the `systemd-networkd dnsstublistener` so I could run my own DNS server. How can I change the nameserver to point to `127.0.0.1` instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `netplan` instead of `resolv.conf`

```
cd /etc/netplan
ls
sudo nano 50-cloud-init.yaml
```

Add `nameservers` entry.

```
network:
    ethernets:
        [network-device]:
            ...
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 2001:4860:4860::8888
                - 2001:4860:4860::8844
                - 8.8.8.8
                - 8.8.4.4
```

Then to apply and test:

```
sudo netplan apply
systemd-resolve --status
```

Answer (score 5):

I discovered that my changes were not being applied to `resolv.conf` because of a symbolic link issue. To fix, I first deleted the file `/etc/resolv.conf`, which was a symbolic link to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf, and then created a new link to /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf.

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```